# ODF document load

Tags: php, openoffice.org, odf

Is there any quick way to read/write an ODF file from PHP?

---- edit -----

I needed this for an ODS(spreadsheet) file

http://www.opendocumentphp.org/ seems to be unmaintained so i didn't even bother.

http://www.phpcraparchive.org/browse/package/4398.html (ods-php) gives an fatal error(tries to allocate more than 512Mb) when opening the file

http://www.odtphp.com/index.php?i=dev&p=Odf if for writing documents only from what i saw(i need to read from spreadsheets also)

http://sourceforge.net/projects/php-o3-template/ (PHP ODF templates) is pre-alpha so again did not try it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There seem to be multiple. OpenDocumentPHP looks most promising:

- http://www.opendocumentphp.org/
- http://www.odtphp.com/index.php?i=dev&p=Odf
- http://sourceforge.net/projects/php-o3-template/
- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenDocument_software
- [http://www.phpcraparchive.org/browse/package/4398.html](http://www.phpclasses.org/browse/package/4398.html)

Evaluate and report back! ;}

Answer (score 0):

[OpenTBS](http://www.tinybutstrong.com/opentbs.php) is a PHP tool that can create OpenDocument files (ODT, ODS, ODF, ODG, ...) using templates. It is also able to read data in OpenDocument files.